# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
  P_Id int NOT NULL,
  LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  FirstName varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Orders (
  O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  OrderNo int NOT NULL,
  P_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

I am getting an error while creating Table Orders:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: leave the two words `FOREIGN KEY` out. Either you use FOREIGN KEY as a separate clause (separated by a comma) and give a field list, or use REFERENCES at the end of an existing field. See Oracle SQL Reference.

Comment: Is there an online tool to help clear up these kinds of errors? My code runs in SQL Developer and it validates in put Cognos 10 report studio, but when I try to generate the SQL it gives this error. I'm guessing it isn't actually caused by parens, but is there a tool to help sort this out?

Comment: Also found this from the IBM Knowledge Center - ORA-00907 may also be caused with queries that use left outer joins and on clauses: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMR4U_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.tg_bitshoot.10.1.1.doc/c_theora-00907errorappearswhenrunningareport.html#TheORA-00907ErrorAppearsWhenRunningaReport

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are defining a foreign key inline with column definition then you shouldn't specify FOREIGN KEY. Drop it from the definition.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders 
( 
  O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  OrderNo int NOT NULL,
  P_Id int REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much , but i have seen examples ,
  P_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)

Comment: Are you sure if those were for Oracle database?

Comment: After searching and being driven mad that I constantly had to define new named constraints to declare a foreign key, This is EXACTLY what the requirement actually is.  W3schools.com is incorrect in their current Oracle fk definition standard