# SQL (Oracle) Problems with foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have a problem with setting a FOREIGN KEY in apex(Oracle). First i created Address table:

```
CREATE TABLE Address
(
  AddressID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Country varchar2( 25 ) NOT NULL,
  City_Village varchar2( 25 ) NOT NULL,
  Street varchar2( 30 ) NOT NULL,
  HomeNumber varchar2( 10 ) NOT NULL,
  Apartment integer NULL
);
```

I tried to create a table Client:

```
CREATE TABLE Client
(
  ClientID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  LastName varchar2( 25 ) NOT NULL,
  FirstName varchar2( 25 ) NOT NULL,
  BirthDate Date NOT NULL,
  Sex char( 1 ) NOT NULL,
  PhoneNumber varchar2( 15 ) NULL,
  Email varchar2( 25 ) NULL,
  IDNP varchar2( 13 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  AddressId integer FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Address( AddressID )
);
```

The error is ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

What's wrong with my code? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE Client
(
  ClientID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  LastName varchar2( 25 ) NOT NULL,
  FirstName varchar2( 25 ) NOT NULL,
  BirthDate Date NOT NULL,
  Sex char( 1 ) NOT NULL,
  PhoneNumber varchar2( 15 ) NULL,
  Email varchar2( 25 ) NULL,
  IDNP varchar2( 13 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  AddressId integer REFERENCES Address( AddressID )
);
```

[ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819869/ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis?rq=1)

Comment: This solution doesn't explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Client
(
  ClientID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  LastName varchar2( 25 ) NOT NULL,
  FirstName varchar2( 25 ) NOT NULL,
  BirthDate Date NOT NULL,
  Sex char( 1 ) NOT NULL,
  PhoneNumber varchar2( 15 ) NULL,
  Email varchar2( 25 ) NULL,
  IDNP varchar2( 13 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  AddressId integer ,
  FOREIGN KEY AddressID REFERENCES Address( AddressID )
);
```